# need to remove first line from a string and then first two word in scala

Tags: scala

I need to import a file and converting it into a string:

The sample input file is:

```
#doc source topic proportion ...
0 src/main/resources/alpha1234 128 0.0651366607249073 26 0.05985658726301475 105 0.047919029870909846 173 0.04677118781397669
```

I only need a part of the string from the second line of the file.
that is from the third word of the second line.

Expected output String

```
128 0.0651366607249073 26 0.05985658726301475 105 0.047919029870909846 173 0.04677118781397669
```

till now I have tried:

```
val inFile  = Source.fromResource("FileName").getLines.mkString(" ").drop(1)
    val out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/main/resources/newResult.txt"))
    out.write(inFile)
    out.close()
```

However It's not dropping the first line, but the first letter only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is you're calling `mkString` first and then `drop`. Function `mkString` converts `Iterator[String]` to `String` and when you call `drop` it works on *chars*. Let's invert order:

```
val lines = Source
    .fromResource("FileName")
    .getLines
    .toList // we convert Iterator to List to allow pattern matching 
    .drop(1) match { // we drop 1st line and then  match the rest
      // we match 1st line, split it by space, drop 2 first words and then assemble everything back together
      case x :: xs => x.split(" ").drop(2).mkString(" ") :: xs
    }

val inFile = lines.mkString(" ")
```